# How Linux handles threads and process scheduling

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, scheduling

I'm trying to understand how Linux handles process scheduling and thread scheduling. I read that Linux can schedule both processes and threads.

Does Linux have a thread scheduler AND a process scheduler? If yes, how do they cooperate?

Comment: It depends on the type of threads you'd like to use. Which thread library are you using?

Comment: I'm speaking in general , about kernel threads not user threads. I don't know  what's a thread library ...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [Linux kernel scheduler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/) is actually scheduling tasks, and these are either threads or (single-threaded) processes.

<sup>So a *task* (a `task_struct` inside the kernel), in the context of the scheduler, is the thing being scheduled, and can be some *kernel thread* like `kworker` or `kswapd`, some *user thread* of a multi-threaded process (like `firefox`), or the single-thread of a *single-threaded process* (like `bash`), identified with that single-threaded process.</sup>

A [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) is a non-empty finite set (sometimes a singleton) of [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) sharing the same [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (and other things like [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), etc etc...). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) etc....

Threads on Linux are **kernel threads** (in the sense of being managed by the kernel, which also creates its own threads), created by the Linux specific [clone](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) syscall (which can also be used to create processes on Linux). The [pthread_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) function is probably built (on Linux) above `clone` inside [NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) and [Gnu Libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) (which integrated NPTL on Linux) and [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/).

Comment: Why is "single-threaded" in brackets? What about multi-threaded processes? They are tasks as well and scheduled by the same scheduler?

Comment: Much more clear. Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch. So actually only the threads inside processes are scheduled (as tasks), no matter is it a multi-threaded or single-threaded process (in addition to kernel threads), not processes themselves?

Comment: What is kernel - scheduled is a task.

Answer (score 26):

Kernel threads under Linux are implemented as processes that share resources. The scheduler does not differentiate between a thread and a process

See here for more information:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/articles/Technical/Linux_Kernel_Thread

Comment: Thanks , that's what I wanted to know. So there is only one scheduler ( which is the process scheduler ) that schedules the "threads" ( which are actually  processes that share the same ressources ). Is this a coorect conclusion ?

Comment: I think a better terminology is that the Linux scheduler is scheduling tasks (implemented as `task_struct` inside the kernel), which may be threads or single-threaded processes or kernel-land threads...

Comment: if "The scheduler does not differentiate between a thread and a process" then how the scheduler is switching context between to threads that belong to the same process and between two threads that belong to different processes? Should n't switching between threads that belong to tow different processes done in different way than threads switching?

Comment: @kachanov To my knowledge it can be handled the same way. Each thread has it's own stack and running execution state (registers etc.) just like "normal" processes. A context switch between two threads that belong to the same process just means that the switch might be a bit faster due to shared memory that may be still in the cache. To avoid simultaneus access of the same memory, the threaded programme has to use mutexes or locks - the scheduler does not help in this case.

Comment: A scheduler is usefully thought of as assigning an amount of CPU resource toi a task.   The link above described KERNEL threads, which are not the same as user-space threads.

Answer (score -6):

Under LINUX there is no concept of threads,to make LINUX POSIX complaint thread is nothing but another process.when you try to get a process id it would display the leader process id under any thread. For more details try to refer this book "Understanding LINUX kernel".Hope

Comment: Fundamentally wrong. There is a difference between processes and threads, with threads being independent flows of excution that runs separately and process encompassing 1 or more threads and its resources.