# Does kernel threads get scheduled by the scheduller?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

How kernel threads gets executed on the CPU
does these kernel threads get scheduled by the scheduller , like normal user space processes? 
or they get waken up when some events happen ?

```
root         2     0  0 Nov30 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 Nov30 ?        00:00:03 [ksoftirqd/0]
```

Comment: this should answer most of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463741/how-linux-handles-threads-and-process-scheduling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes - kernel threads gets scheduled just like user threads and they are normally blocking pending certain events (different events per kernel thread).

Comment: Oky right , But why they are represented as processes?

Comment: @user3718463 What makes you think they are?

Comment: @user3718463 they are not represented as processes. They are processes. Or to be more accurate, they are just a bunch of schedulable tasks (a.k.a threads) which happens to not have a user space portion.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes.

Only major difference between kernel threads and user space process would be task->mm = NULL for kernel threads.

Hence they don't have distinct address space. Rest is pretty much same for kernel threads and user space processes.