# Understanding the concept of LWP in liunx kernel

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I study the OS book[operating system concepts] written by Silberschatz recently.

At chapter 5, the book describes the concept of "Contention scope", and mentions that there are two types of contention scope. One is PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS and the other is PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM.

And for PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, the user level thread will bind to one LWP[virtual processor], and this LWP will attaches to one kernel thread.

Actually, I'm not quite understanding the concept of LWP. 
On the command line terminal I can type the following command:

```
ps -eLf
```

And I can see one process[PID] may have several LWP[thread IDs]. By doing some survey, I found that LWP seems simply mean thread or tasks in linux.
like  the following link:

[How Linux handles threads and process scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463741/how-linux-handles-threads-and-process-scheduling)

So I have the following two questions:

**Q1 :**
Is LWP defined as virtual processor in linux? what source code in kernel defines it?

**Q2:**
In the following picture, syslog has the PID [852] and has four threads. And these four LWPs will each bind one kernel thread? Or kernel will just schedule them directly?

[image]

The above picture is taken from:

http://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/ps-command-usage-examples-in-linux

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux does not support `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS`. See for example http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setscope.3.html

> POSIX.1 requires that an implementation support at least one of these
>   contention scopes.  Linux supports PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, but not
>   PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS.

In Linux, a process' multiple threads are like separate processes that happen to share the same address space. Yes, this is a complete oversimplification, they share other resources as well -- notably, signal handlers, file descriptors and various IDs -- and there are other more subtle differences, but they are each full-fledged independently schedulable entities. The terminology used within the kernel is "task". Every process has at least one task. A multithreaded process has more than one.

Q1: LWP is not the same as a virtual processor (whatever you mean by that -- it's not something that's familiar in this context). An LWP corresponds to a task in linux. Although outside kernel development, "process" and "thread" are still the more common terms.

Q2: Each LWP corresponds to a separate task (or user thread), and each is separately schedulable by the kernel. (In linux, the term "kernel thread" has a specific meaning that is quite different: a kernel thread is a thread [really task] which spends its entire life inside the kernel. They're typically used for various internal housekeeping functions.)

For more on the Posix threading model, see this very good explanation: http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/pthread-scheduling.html that discusses linux and FreeBSD implementations.

And this one, for more general threading concepts: http://timetobleed.com/threading-models-so-many-different-ways-to-get-stuff-done/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen the second article. The second article mentions three kind of mapping for user threads to kernel threads and it says Linux implements 1:1 model.                                                                    So will each user thread mapping to one kernel thread in linux [i.e. Will the four syslog lwp each maps to one kernel thread in my question post]?  Can I see this kind of relationship from the ps command? And from your reply, it seems that kernel will view user threads and kernel threads are all the "tasks" and schedule them directly, right?

Comment: Yes. Each syslog lwp (user thread) is in fact a task. And the term "task" in linux corresponds to what that article calls "kernel thread". But again note that the term "kernel thread" has a specific meaning *in linux* that is different than the sense you are using it in. In linux, both user threads and kernel threads are tasks and both are independently schedulable.

Comment: Ok. Since user threads and kernel threads are all schedulable tasks in linux. There is no such 1:1 binding like the article saying  in linux right?

Comment: Er, no. What 1:1 means is that there *is* a binding from "kernel thread" to user thread (in the sense the article is using that term). I have simply been trying to distinguish their use of the term "kernel thread" as being in conflict with a linux *term of art* (see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/term-of-art). In that article, "kernel thread" means roughly "independently scheduled entity"; but in linux, "kernel thread" means "independently scheduled entity that also spends its entire life in kernel mode".

Comment: In your previous comment: each lwp(user thread) is task. And the term task is corresponding to the "kernel thread in that article sense " I think I'm a little confusing about this, why each lwp is user thread but also kernel thread(in that article sense). Originally, I think since there is a user thread, so there is a kernel thread mapping to it. So can I say syslog 852 is the user thread(in that article sense), and since it is also a scheduable task(kernel thread in that article sense), so it is called 1:1 binding?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In that article's terminology, "user thread" is what your code expresses (think of it as independent execution path), "kernel thread" is the schedulable entity. In linux, those are 1 to 1. And so every thread can (or could) run simultaneously if you have enough processors.

Comment: For contrast, in the `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS ` model, there is only 1 schedulable entity, and multiple user threads compete to run within it. So only one of the user threads can execute at any given instant.  (Call that M:1; then M:N is a generalization of that model where you have more than one schedulable entity but fewer than the total number of user threads.)